# Add-in crashes and experiences redirect loops after switching to Edge backed Desktop Web App Viewer

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have noticed that our add-in is exhibiting the following behaviour for certain users:

1. Random redirection loops (Our add-in is an Angular application)
2. The application fails to load and displays a message saying that the "application failed to load"
3. The Desktop Web App Viewer is visible in the Task Manager even after Outlook is closed

Once again, this is happening for a subset of our users without any visible pattern.

Edge version: 44.18362.267.0

EDIT:

Added error messages:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which client are you using? Are you using the rich desktop Outlook client on Windows, or on a Mac, or the web client in a browser?

Comment: We are using the Windows 10 Desktop client (Outlook 2016)

Comment: Is this a taskpane addin? Could you also share more details on when the application fails to load? The first time you load the taskpane? What happens when after you get the error, close and reopen the addin, do you still see it happening? What version of Outlook are you on? A screenshot of the error will be helpful too.

Comment: It is a taskpane addin.
The add-in fails to load when it is opened for the first time (some users cannot load it at all).
Closing and opening the add-in a few times allows the add-in to load.
Outlook version: 16.0.12026.20100 32 bit.

EDIT: Added screenshots

Comment: The first error is when a long running script is detected. Make sure the js within Office.initialize is not taking too long. A simple check would be to create a simple add-in and doing almost nothing in office.initialize(or commenting code out line by line within initialize) to see if that loads. If so, then you'll need to look at your behavior within the initialize function to make sure it doesn't take too long. The second error happens when restart limit has been reached. We automatically re-try loading the addin thrice after failures. If all attempts fail, that's when this error is shown.